# popup page php data doesn't show on submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a table has php variables fetched from `mysql` , the table is inside a `Form` , what i am trying to do is to display page to be printed for the user with a an invoice style layout, i tried to make a behavior that when the `FORM` Is submitted , a pop up page will come  display the `php variables data` , which is doesn't work at all , i tried to display the `content` of popup page inside a regluar page , it worked ! , which means there is no problem with my php code .

here is the form page code :

```
<form action="../../printInvoice.php" method="post" onsubmit="MM_openBrWindow('../../printInvoice.php','Invoice','status=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
    <td align="left">Invoice:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="12%" height="39" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Invoice Number</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Event Name</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Reservation Date</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Quantity</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Price Per Ticket</td>
    <td width="12%" bgcolor="#9DE3FB" align="center">Total Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="invoiceId" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['invoiceId']; ?>" class ="field-style"/></td>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="eventTitle" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['name']; ?>" class="field-style" /></td>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="invoiceDate" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['invoiceDate']; ?>" class="field-style" /></td>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="invoiceqty" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['quantity'] ?>" class="field-style" /></td>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="invoicePPU" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['price']; ?>" class="field-style" /></td>
    <td width="12%" height="39" align="center"><input type="text" name="invoiceTotal" readonly="readonly" value="<? echo $row['totalPrice']; ?>" class="field-style" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Print Invoice" />
</form>
```

here is the popup window code (invoice layout to print ):

```
<table width="65%" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="60%"><img src="images/Logo.png" /></td>
        <td width="40%"><p>Invoice No:# <? echo $invoiceId; ?></p>
          <p>Invoice Date: <? echo $invoiceDate ;?> </p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="125" colspan="5" valign="top"><p>Bill To:</p>
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p>Address:</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="12%" align="center" height="40">Item Id</td>
    <td width="28%" align="center">Item Disc</td>
    <td width="9%" align="center">QTY</td>
    <td width="40%" align="center">Price Per Unit</td>
    <td width="11%" align="center">Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">1</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><? echo $eventTitle . " ticket(s)"; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><? echo $invoiceqty ; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><? echo $invoicePPU ; ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><? echo $invoiceqty * $invoicePPU ; ?></td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

for submitting behavior, i used Dreamweaver behavior panel. what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about dreamweaver behaviour but as far as I can tell this will never work.

You are posting the data to a the "../../printInvoice.php" but when you request the popup page you are opening a new instance that hasn't received the post data.

You need to alter your javascript that pops the page up so that it posts the forms data when it performs the popup request.

I don't know which library you are using to create your popup but fancybox (Jquery plugin: http://fancybox.net) allows you to post data to the popup it creates.

If you could tell me what popup library you are using I might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use php to show a popup you must use ajax, and javascript :

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
           //show your Popup
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: What? Then how did they do all those annoying popups in the 90's before AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried to use `$row['invoiceId'];` instaed of `$invoiceId` in the popupwindow?
>
> It seems to be the same file and therfore the $row[] data should be accessable!
>
> If this doesn't works we propably need more code, especially of the php side.

^^ Overlooked something, we definitely need more code!

Answer (score 0):

thanks, instead of all of this , i posted all the variables as `url` parameters such as :

```
<onsubmit="MM_openBrWindow('../../printInvoice.php?invoiceId=<? echo $row['invoiceId']; ?>&eventTitle=<? echo $row['name']; ?>','Invoice'
```

thanks for trying & your time everyone :)